# Refreshing a navbar view controller

Tags: iphone

On my default navbar's root view (a chatroom of sorts) I have a title bar, with a rightBarButton "compose", which pops up a `UITextView` and keyboard to enter a new chat message. After you hit "send", the message sends back to the server to store it in the DB, that works fine.

When I close the `UITextView` and load the root view back, I do:

```
[newMessageEntry resignFirstResponder];
[self loadView];
```

That does show the chat messages successfully, but I'm not sure how to auto-refresh it so it picks up the message you just submitted. I'm thinking the `self loadView` doesn't really load up the view with all the code, because in that view's `viewDidLoad` method, I start the code to load the messages from the server and display them, but that code is not running.

Am I making any sense?

Answer (score 2):

From help on another forum, hoping this helps some people here:

I needed to use

```
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
[self loadView];
```

setNeedsDisplay set that view to be refreshed with data when it's loaded up.